# Rebus: Guess this movie

Tags: rebus, movies

Another Simple Rebus. Guess this movie name

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's with the red color on the Indian map?

Comment: It's not red. It's saffron. And is the first color in Indian flag

Comment: @Techidiot it's more of shade of saffron rather then red, part of [Indian flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_India#Design_and_construction_details)

Comment: @AnkitSharma- Yeah. It has a little bit of extra red I guess. No worries good one OP. +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solution:

> [**Now You See Me**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_You_See_Me_(film)):
> 9 in Northern Regions of India is pronounced as = नौ or *NAU* (Hindi),
>  Initial Velocity is denoted as = *U*,
>  SE+E = *SEE*,
>  **M**iddle **E**ast = *ME*

Comment: Good one! +1 Nau(Hindi) :D

Comment: @Walt I'm used to be impressed by your prowesses on [Movies SE](http://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4386/walt), but now you came to impress us here!

Comment: @IAmInPLS he is omnipotent

Comment: To be more clear, in northern regions of India. That's why 9 was placed in that specific area.